# Input Date to Written form

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to write an inputted date from the adjacent cell.
i.e. date entered in A1, B1 = A1 but in word form **(in Spanish)**.

I'm close to a solution but I'm sure making things more complicated than they need to be.

The date column`(A)` is currently being separated into 3;

day`(B)`, month`(D)`, year`(F)`, using; `=LEFT($A1;2)`, `=MID($A1;4;2)`, `=RIGHT($A1;4)` accordingly.

In Columns `C`,`E`,`G` I'm using

`=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.buscapalabra.com/numeros-a-letras.html?cifra="&B1;"//li[1]//strong");1)`

where `B1` changes to `E1`, `F1` depending on the column

finally in column `H` where the date will be written I use:

```
=trim(LOwer($C2&"de "&TEXT($D2;"mmmm")&" de "&$F2))&If(Value(Right($E2;1))=1;If(Value(MID($E2;4;1))<>1;"o";"");"")
```

For some reason the text value returned from the site has a space on the end and also does not properly word numbers ending in 1. Hence the use of `TRIM()` & the nested `IF()`

It works for now, I haven't tested it exhaustedly but I'd love to hear what people think, I'm new to Sheets but there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what's in the source cell (a sheets date, or a string? And if it's the latter, what string?) as well as the expected output? A screenshot of this could be very useful, or a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XLDeakXnpuprkI79iMxRPaVNYc5lkYeEeWPaBbUkCF0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @lamblichus hope the link works

Comment: Hi Sebastián, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801116), let me know if this is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use custom functions:

You could do this with an Apps Script [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting **Tools > Script editor**, and copy the following functions to the script (check inline comments for more information):

```
function DATE_IN_WORDS(date) {
  const day = date.getDate(); // Day of the month in numbers
  const year = date.getFullYear(); // Year in numbers
  const options = { month: 'long'};
  const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES', options).format(date); // Month in words
  const dayAndYear = [day, year].map(number => { // Retrieve word for day and year
    const url = "https://www.buscapalabra.com/numeros-a-letras.html?cifra=" + number
    const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const first = "<em>Como sustantivo:</em> El <strong>";
    const cut = resp.substring(resp.indexOf(first), resp.length);
    let word = cut.substring(first.length, cut.indexOf("</strong>")); // Get desired section of HTML
    if (number.toString().slice(-1) == "1" && number.toString().slice(-2) != "11") {
      word = word.trim() + "o"; // Replace "un" with "uno"
      let arrayWord = word.split(" ");
      let lastWord = arrayWord.pop();
      if (lastWord === "veintiúno") { // If 21, replace "ú" with "u"
        lastWord = lastWord.replace("ú", "u");
        arrayWord.push(lastWord);
        word = arrayWord.join(" ");
      }
      return word;
    } else return word;
  });
  return dayAndYear.join("de " + month + " de "); // Join day, month and year
}
```

This function uses:

- [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to retrieve the month in Spanish.
- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) to fetch information from `https://www.buscapalabra.com/numeros-a-letras.html`.

Once it is defined, you can use the function `DATE_IN_WORDS` the same you would any sheets built-in function. This function would accept the cell with the `Date` as a parameter.

#### Example:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: @lamblichus Script works great, there is a slight loading time but I'm guessing this is due to the url data fetch.

Comment: @lamblichus Weird error, for some reason when entering a date containing the month of march, all day values are one less than they should be.

Comment: @SebastiánH It might be a time zone problem. Make sure the [spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and the [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()) have the same timezone (even though it's strange only march is failing).

Comment: @lamblichus there is a difference in the time zones, my sheets being an hour ahead of the script. Thing is, I need the Sheet to be in the local timezone and from what I found you cant change the time zone for sctipts. Do you think I could add some sort of +/- hours in order to be in the same time zone? I worry that then the issue would be of when time zones change would the calculation be off again.

Comment: @SebastiánH You can change the script timezone. Just set it in the `timeZone` field of your [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#manifest) (see [editing a manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest)).

Comment: @lamblichus, you nailed it. having changed that it seems to be working properly. I'll be doing a more exhaustive testing soon. Let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @lamblichus I´ve found another bug I need to deal with :P 
When the year is a compound word, e.g. veintiuno and not veinte y uno, it tildates the 'u' in uno making it 'veintiúno which is incorrect. 
Im unsure why this happens, any thoughts?

Comment: @SebastiánH Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this will only happen with 21. If that's the case, you can just check whether the last word in year is 21 and replace `ú` with `u` if that's the case. I updated my answer with that.

Comment: @lamblichus much appreciated, it appears it is only in the case of 21. thanks again for your help